# Unknown Audio Device

Tags: 14.04, sound, headset

I plugged in a mobile headset (in-ear speakers with mic) but this keeps popping up.

> **Unknown Audio Device**
>   What kind of device did you plug in?
>   Headphones | Headset | Microphone
>   Cancel     |     Sound Settings
>
> [image]

Is there any place in the file-system where I can hardcode this setting ?

```
anjanesh@anjanesh-Latitude-3560:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i jack
ii  libjack-jackd2-0:amd64                                1.9.9.5+20130622git7de15e7a-1ubuntu1                     amd64        JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Latitude 3560 laptop.

Comment: There's a lot : https://pastebin.com/ahZQPwhG

Comment: @hellomoto you suggested wrong command (it lists all jack related packages in repository). @anjanesh - please add output of correct command - `dpkg -l | grep -i jack` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert: Added

Comment: What happens if you click on *Sound Settings* button?

Comment: I think it shows the sound settings which shows up when I goto main settings - I don't know for sure as the popup has stopped now - it pops up like 100 times only when plugging in the headset or restart the laptop. Everything works, it's just that this dialog box occasionally pops up which is very irritating.

Comment: @ anjanesh  - what if all these problems are caused by bad cable / faulty headset? Did you try to test with other headset?

Comment: It's a brand new mobile headset.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the source of this window. It is `unity-settings-daemon`'s plugin located in [line 99 of `plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/dialog-window.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/dialog-window.c#L99) (in `dialog_create` function, called later by [`wdypi_dialog_run`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/dialog-window.c#L130)):

```
88    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(d->dialog), _("Unknown Audio Device"));
...
99    d->label = gtk_label_new(_("What kind of device did you plug in?"));
...
103   d->hp_btn = create_icon_button(WDYPI_DIALOG_HEADPHONES, _("Headphones"), "audio-headphones");
...
106   d->hs_btn = create_icon_button(WDYPI_DIALOG_HEADSET, _("Headset"), "audio-headset");
...
110   d->mic_btn = create_icon_button(WDYPI_DIALOG_MICROPHONE, _("Microphone"), "audio-input-microphone");
...
115   d->cancel_btn = gtk_dialog_add_button(GTK_DIALOG(d->dialog), _("Cancel"), GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL);
116   d->settings_btn = gtk_dialog_add_button(GTK_DIALOG(d->dialog), _("Sound Settings…"), GTK_RESPONSE_YES);
```

This dialog is shown by PulseAudio event [see line 2720 of plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c#L2720): `on_control_card_info_updated` calls [`pa_backend_card_changed`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/pa-backend.c#L130) (then it calls [`get_headset_ports`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/pa-backend.c#L66)) :

```
static headset_ports get_headset_ports(const pa_card_info *c)
{
    headset_ports h = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c->n_ports; i++) {
        pa_card_port_info *p = c->ports[i];
        if (!strcmp(p->name, "analog-output-headphones"))
            h.headphones = p;
        else if (!strcmp(p->name, "analog-input-microphone-headset"))
            h.headsetmic = p;
        else if (!strcmp(p->name, "analog-input-microphone"))
            h.headphonemic = p;
    }
    return h;
}
```

and finally shows dialog with [`on_wdypi_popup`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c#L2712) and [`wdypi_dialog_run`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/unity-settings-daemon/trusty-security/view/head:/plugins/media-keys/what-did-you-plug-in/dialog-window.c#L130).

In the installed system this phrase (*"What kind of device did you plug in?"*) is found in:

```
unity-settings-daemon: /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/usd-test-media-keys
unity-settings-daemon: /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libmedia-keys.so
```

According to source code clicking on "Sound Settings" will open `unity-control-center sound`.

---

Note: the `libjack-jackd2-0:amd64` package is pre-installed on clean Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
$ aptitude why libjack-jackd2-0:amd64
i   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good Depends libjack-jackd2-0 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) | libjack-0.116                                 

$ aptitude why gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
i   rhythmbox Depends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good (>= 1.0.6)
```

Sound is maintained by PulseAudio and then by Unity Settings Daemon.